# Get iPhone app to use carrier data as wifi has no internet

Tags: iphone, xcode, wifi, cdn, reachability

I have an app that talks to a network via wifi. My issue is that the wifi network has no internet connection, so I want to use the carrier network to talk to the outside world whilst also connected to wifi.

I've done some searching but haven't found a solution to my problem. A number of answers refer to Reachability, but the Reachability classes indicate what connection is available but can't confirm if a site is reachable (fair enough as the site may be down).

Basically I want to force my app to use CDN for some URLs even if it is connected to a WIFI network that it uses for other URLs.

Can this be done programatically? Otherwise the user would have to manually turn on/off the wifi network to get the app to use CDN.

Thanks

Comment: So far I know, there is no mechanism available to force the Network usage. The iOS device decide itself to use available `CDN` or `Wifi`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot force the OS to use Carrier network for internet through your code.

If WIFI is available through which the phone is connected and that wifi network does not have internet - there is no way you can force your app to use Carrier network for internet connection - so its pointless to know if the wifi network does have internet connectivity.

as for the other case, if user switch off wifi manually, OS will automatically switch to Carrier network for internet.

Answer (score 1):

Like samfisher said programmatically it's not possible as of the moment, not through the public APIs.

If it does help, please check this [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35116-using-cellular-data-network-while-wifi-connected.html).

I have a similar problem, but in my application I only communicate with one AP at a time just to check its SSID, so the simple knowledge of not setting a default gateway and DNS servers I got from the discussion is enough to solve my problem. Like Waqas Raja said, the iOS device decides itself whether to use `CDN` or `Wifi`, so by not setting up a DNS server and a default gateway I think (not a very knowledgeable guy with networking BTW) it makes the iPhone not route to the internet using the WiFi Access Point connection, and thus connects to the internet using `CDN`.

So in my opinion, as long as the iPhone recognizes that the WiFi Network has no possible way of routing to an internet connection, it will turn to the `CDN`.

I hope this answer helps as it is my first attempt at doing so.